# printf() seems to change a variable

Tags: c++

I'm a cpp beginner and have trouble to understand why, in the following code, the printf()... function seems to *change* some variables. Is something wrong in the code, or in my compiler instalation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

class Node
{
public:
    int val;
    Node * next;

    Node(int v) { // constructor
        val=v;
        next=NULL;
    }
};

class Stack
{
public:
    Node *head;
    Stack(int i) // constructor
    {
        Node n(i);
        head=&n;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Stack s(1);
    printf("s.head->next: %p\n",s.head->next);
    printf("s.head->next: %p\n",s.head->next);
}
```

I get the following output:

```
s.head->next: 00000000
s.head->next: FFFFFFFE
```

How is that possible that I don't get the same? (I got similar problems when using the std:cout function instead, but the minimal code would be longer).
 Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Use std::cout instead of printf.

Comment: @manni66  I tried but the problem appeared anyway at some point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
  Node n(i);
```

creates a local variable, that you then store the address of:

```
  head=&n;
```

and use that address later.

After that, all bets are off, as you are in undefined behaviour land.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I had suspision that this is wrong. However, even though, is it possible that the printf() function does not behave in a deterministic way?

Comment: It's useless to reason about a program once it is in UB territory. Simply don't go there.

Comment: @PeterFranek Like Neil said, what you do is totally undefined behavior. This could erase your DD, create a new dimension in the space time or maybe send poney on Mars. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @PeterFranek: what is happening is that `printf` is using the stack for its own purposes (which it has every right to do). It has its own data at the address pointed to by `head`, which it is overwriting.